# How do you convert a folder to zip file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to convert a whole folder (including it's contents) into a `.zip` file?

Answer (score 3):

There is no class for doing this in the .NET Framework itself, but you can use some of the third-party libraries. An open-source [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) seems to be quite good and has a lot of examples to get you started. You'll just need to recursively iterate over all files in the given folder and add them one by one.

Comment: but sir , how to upload folder in my website?

Comment: @Rajuu Now that's another question. Do you mean folder from the client's PC? I don't know a good answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9ce6c242-c14c-4969-9251-af95e4cf320f/zip--unzip-folders-and-f.aspx) appears to have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Xceed Zip libraries in the past for this and found them very easy to use.  The full license is quite pricey, but they do have a 45 day, 100% functional free trial available here:

http://xceed.com/Zip_Net_Intro.html